# Add key value on all objects inside an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this on MongoDB:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b7"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Peter'},
  {name: 'John'}
 ]
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b8"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Harry'},
  {name: 'Nik'}
 ]
}
```

Now I want to add one more key values to all objects under arrayHolder objects. I am sharing the Expected Output:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b7"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Peter', valid: true },
  {name: 'John', valid: true}
 ]
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b8"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Harry', valid: true},
  {name: 'Nik', valid: true}
 ]
}
```

For this I wrote the query but that query will add the new object inside the array rather than adding one more key-value under the objects.

My Query is:

```
db.Collection.updateMany({}, {$push: {arrayHolder: {$each: {valid: true}}}})
```

This Query will add the new Objects inside an array. I am sharing the output which I am getting after this query run:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b7"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Peter'},
  {name: 'John'},
  {valid: true}
 ]
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b02a197cca91d3476a3b8"),
 arrayHolder: [
  {name: 'Harry'},
  {name: 'Nik'},
  {valid: true}
 ]
}
```

Is there anyone who guide me where I have done the mistakes and how to fire the proper query so that expected output will achieved.

*Thanks in advance for the people who interacted with this problem*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [all positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to do that:

```
db.Collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {'arrayHolder.$[].valid': true}})
```